# Property .then undefined error

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I keep getting a .then undefined error in the checkB function below.

```
export function checkB(accountId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const myRepo = new myRepo();
      myRepo.checkC(accountId).then( results => {
        return resolve(results));
      });
    });
}
```

I am able to call checkC and get back a json response.

```
checkC(){
  const fetchApi = new FetchApi();
  const url = `${config.routes.base}/mypath/5`;
  fetchApi.get(url).then(results => {
    return results.json().then(json => {
      return json;
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

I have a  an initial fucntion checkA() that calls CheckB - am trying to get the results in CheckA synchronously  but keep running into the .then undefined error from CheckB.

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: `checkC` doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from `checkC()`:

```
checkC(){
  const fetchApi = new FetchApi();
  const url = `${config.routes.base}/mypath/5`;
  return fetchApi.get(url)
    .then(results => results.json());
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

Also, since `results.json()` is a Promise which returns *results*, you do not need to do the `.then(json => {return json;});` thing.

And, more in general, if you need to do something with the result of a promise which is itself the result of another promise, you can chain them without the need of nested code.

You can write your second example like that (it is useless, first code I wrote works fine, just for the sake of an example):

```
const fetchApi = new FetchApi();
const url = `${config.routes.base}/mypath/5`;
fetchApi.get(url).then(results => {
  return results.json();
})
.then(json => {
  return json;
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```